# Screen State not Updating from AsyncStorage when going back

Tags: react-native, react-redux, state, asyncstorage

I'm building a React Native app.
My app has 5 Screens: Home (initialRouteName), DeckPage, QuestionPage, NewCardPage, NewDeckPage. (in this order)
I'm using Redux for state management. The state is updating from AsyncStorage.
The component that does the fetching is the class component "Home" by dispatching the "fetching" function in componentDidMount.

Component NewCardPage, NewDeckPAge are also updating the state with new content by dispatching the same fetching function as the Home when a button is pressed.

My problem appears when I want to delete a Deck component from inside DeckPage parent component. The function that does this job has this functionality: after removing the item from AsyncStorage, updates the STATE, and moves back to Screen HOME. The issue is that when I go back to HOME component the state doesn't update with the latest info from AsyncStorage.
This is not the case when I'm doing the same operation in the other 2 components NewCardPage, NewDeckPage.

I'll paste the code below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList } from "react-native";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import AddDeckButton from "../components/AddDeckButton";
import DeckInList from "../components/DeckInList";
import { receiveItemsAction } from "../redux/actions";

class Home extends Component {
  
   componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAsyncStorageContent();
  }


  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return <DeckInList {...item} />;
  };

  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    // console.log(items);

    const deckNumber = Object.keys(items).length;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Header />
        <View style={styles.decksInfoContainer}>
          <View style={styles.deckNumber}>
            <View style={{ marginRight: 50 }}>
              <Text style={styles.deckNumberText}>{deckNumber} Decks</Text>
            </View>
            <AddDeckButton />
          </View>

          <View style={{ flex: 0.9 }}>
            <FlatList
              data={Object.values(items)}
              renderItem={this.renderItem}
              keyExtractor={(item) => item.title}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    items: state.items,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getAsyncStorageContent: () => dispatch(receiveItemsAction()),
  };
};
```

-----------DECKPAGE COMPONENT------------

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Deck from "../components/Deck";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { removeItemAction, receiveItemsAction } from "../redux/actions";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";

const DeckPage = ({ route, navigation }) => {
  
  const { title, date } = route.params;
  const questions = useSelector((state) => state.items[title].questions);
  const state = useSelector((state) => state.items);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleRemoveIcon = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem(title, () => {
      dispatch(receiveItemsAction());
      navigation.goBack();
    });
  };

  console.log(state);
  return (
    <View style={styles.deckPageContainer}>
      <Deck
        handleRemoveIcon={handleRemoveIcon}
        title={title}
        questions={questions}
        date={date}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

-----------This is my ACTIONS file----------

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
export const RECEIVE_ITEMS = "RECEIVE_ITEMS";
// export const REMOVE_ITEM = "REMOVE_ITEM";

export const receiveItemsAction = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const objectValues = {};
  try {
    const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
    if (keys.length !== 0) {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
      if (jsonValue != null) {
        for (let element of jsonValue) {
          objectValues[element[0]] = JSON.parse(element[1]);
        }
        dispatch({
          type: RECEIVE_ITEMS,
          payload: objectValues,
        });
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

-----This is my REDUCERS file----

```
import { RECEIVE_ITEMS, REMOVE_ITEM } from "./actions";

const initialState = {
};

const items = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_ITEMS:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
      };
    // case REMOVE_ITEM:
    //   return {
    //     ...state,
    //     ...action.payload,
    //   };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default items;
```

-----This is my UTILS file----

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";



export const removeDeckFromAsyncStorage = async (title)=>{
  try{
    
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem(title);
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log(`Error trying to remove deck from AsyncStorage ${e}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thorough question, but somewhat lengthy. If you could reduce the code to the shortest, simplest example of your issues that'd be helpful.

Comment: I tried to delete some of the code, I hope now is easier to understand the issue.